# How do you permanently add include and library paths to ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables

I have added the following environment variables to the end of my bash.bashrc

```
CPATH=$CPATH:/usr/custom/include
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/custom/lib
PATH=$PATH:/usr/custom/bin
```

But when I try to run make with a file needing ncurses it fails. 
ncurses.h is located at /usr/custom/include/ncurses (I tried cpath there too)

```
"fatal error: ncurses.h: No such file or directory
 #include<ncurses.h>"
```

Comment: Did you `export CPATH` so the compiler also sees that environment variable? (I'd probably instead use `pkg-config --libs --cflags ncurses` but that assumes that `pkg-config` is available and configured...)

Comment: I changed the .bashrc to export CPATH, still no go.